# VMWare Server On Ubuntu Server

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vmware-server

I'm running a project at the moment that requires me to install VMWare server on one of our spare servers.... and consolidate some of our older machines, that aren't so "critical"

I was just wondering if Ubuntu Server was a good OS to install VMWare server on?
Is it possible to have Windows VM's hosted within this?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmserver2.pdf)

```
Linux Host Operating System

Requirements ... 
Ubuntu Linux 8.04
Ubuntu Linux 7.10 
Ubuntu Linux 7.04
Ubuntu Linux 6.10
Ubuntu Linux 6.06
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer is yes on both questions

Answer (score 0):

Yes and yes.  :)  Last I check, VMware is supported on Ubuntu.  And you can run Windows on VMware.

Answer (score 0):

Quasi-unrelated but I suggest you look at VMware ESXi before VMware Server; you'll find the performance to be orders of magnitude better.